# Restricting Google Places Api results

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

Is it possible to restrict Gopogle Places API to return result within a particular region. I want to retrive results inside Delhi/NCR region. Let's say when I type S in my textfield, it should return Sohna Road, sector 49, gurgaon (and other Delhi/NCR regions) but not State of Kerala, India.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can achieve this by using the right `location` and `radius` according to the [developers guide](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) :

- **location** — The point around which you wish to retrieve place
  information. Must be specified as latitude,longitude.
- **radius** — The distance (in meters) within which to return place
  results. Note that setting a radius biases results to the indicated
  area, but may not fully restrict results to the specified area.

Comment: These parameters are OK, but they are just bias, there is no strict filter for regions. You can find a feature request for this in public issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9242. However, no any timeline from Google at the moment.